# Transposing rows to columns in MsAccess query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with

> cID, side, row, column

with some data of

```
24, 1, 10, 5
25, 1, 12, 6
24, 2, 18, 3
```

and so on. Now I want these data to be show in the form of:

```
cID=24
side    1   2
row    10  18
column  5   3

cID=25
side     2
row     12
column   6
```

The cID is filtered in the query so the output will be the 3 rows (side, row, column) and the data of them of a specific cID.
Is that possible with MsAccess Query/SQL and how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something on these lines:

```
TRANSFORM First(q.rvalue) AS firstofrow
SELECT q.rhead
FROM   (SELECT cid,
               side,
               row   AS rvalue,
               "row" AS rhead
        FROM   atable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT cid,
               side,
               column   AS rvalue,
               "column" AS rhead
        FROM   atable) AS q
WHERE   q.cid = 24
GROUP  BY q.rhead
PIVOT q.side;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Remou. Your solution is close to what I want, but the rhead is a head of the results. I want it also a row data. And for head we can use a numbering 1,2,3... or the autonumbering ID which provided by table definition (I didn't include this field in the question, but there is).

Comment: Paste the data you did provide into a table called atable. You will find that both row and column are returned. You can use the idea to work with the data you did not provide.